# jQuery tooltip not working as expected - REVISED

Tags: jquery, function, popup, tooltip

Ok I fixed the original problem but I would like now is to add the title value back to the anchor tag of id="contact" from the id="contact-info" popup before I remove the popup

The JS

```
this.contactPreview = function() {
jQuery("a.contact").click(function(e){
        this.t = this.title;
        this.title = "";
        var c = (this.t != "") ? "<br />" + this.t : "";
        jQuery("body").append("<p id='contact-info'>"+ this.t + "<a id='close-contact' class='close-contact' style='color:red;'>Close</a></p>");
        jQuery("#contact-info")
            .css("top", (e.pageY - xOffset) + "px")
            .css("left", (e.pageX + yOffset) + "px")
            .fadeIn(500);
    });

    jQuery("a.close-contact").live('click', function(){
        // Need to re-insert the popup info into the original title tag of contact
        jQuery('#contact-info').remove();          
    });
};

// Use jQuery() instead of $()for WordPress compatibility with the included prototype js library which uses $()
// http://ipaulpro.com/blog/tutorials/2008/08/jquery-and-wordpress-getting-started/
// See http://chrismeller.com/using-jquery-in-wordpress
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Call the function here
    contactPreview();

});
```

The CSS

```
#contact-info{
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background:#333;
    padding:5px;
    display:none;
    color:#fff;
```

The HTML

```
<a class='contact' title='Some info to display'>Display Info</a>
```

Thanks in advance for any help on this

Comment: @Phill Pafford - if your original problem is solved, you should tick the answer that solved it and ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live will do the trick.

This will automatically add the click event when the CLOSE `<A>` is created. What you did is you added the event when the document is loaded, but the CLOSE `<A>` is not loaded yet.

```
$("a.close-contact").live("click", function()
{
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Comment: hmm that seems to fix one of the problem, now I can get the alert function to work, but it cant find the id of the original tag to remove it. BTW I added the live() to the popup

Comment: still need to re-insert the popup display values into the original title tag for #contact

Comment: The question had 2 parts and you really helped me on the first part (sorry I thought I had posted both parts in the first edit of the post, my bad). any chance you could help me with the second part???

Comment: Maybe using parent?? jQuery Docs->Traversing